# Where is the list of the cheezy page-object dynamic element finders?

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

As a reference I am referring to [this](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/203#issuecomment-37946345) post.

It basically says instead of saying `text_field(:tf_elem, id:'id1')`. We can do `text_field_element(id: 'id1')`. I definitely prefer the latter. It also works for multiple elements so `text_field_elements`. I can't seem to figure out how to do it for radio buttons. I'm trying `radio_elements` but not working. Undefined method. Frustratingly enough I can't find this information documented anywhere else. How do I get it to work for radio buttons and is there a "cheat sheat" for future reference for all the elements using the `text_field_element`/`text_field_elements` style?

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic locators are included:

- For the PageObject by [ElementLocators](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/d1e64b0fcee4332787c848c10a631a35e83267b8/lib/page-object/element_locators.rb)
- For the Elements by [NestedElements](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/d1e64b0fcee4332787c848c10a631a35e83267b8/lib/page-object/nested_elements.rb)

For the bulk of the methods, they use the shared [LocatorGenerator](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/d1e64b0fcee4332787c848c10a631a35e83267b8/lib/page-object/locator_generator.rb). In there, the list of BASIC_ELEMENTS and ADVANCED_ELEMENTS suffixed by "_element" and "elements" are the dynamic locator methods.

As an example, for radio elements, there is a "radio_button" in the ADVANCED_ELEMENTS array. The dynamic methods would then be:

- `radio_button_element` for the first match and
- `radio_button_elements` for all matches.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a similar question that I didn't think fit here . Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164940/cheezy-dynamic-finder-for-page-section