# Cheezy Dynamic Finder for Page Section

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

I'm on ruby using the page-object-gem by cheezy. Following the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59077554/4701396), I decided to ask this question (a `page_section` isn't an element I think). Anyway what is the syntax for the dynamic finder/locator for a `page_section` and `page_sections`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this scenario was considered in the original design, so there is not great support. Feel free to request it at https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues .

That said, you could use the internal `platform` object's `#page_for` and `#pages_for` methods. The parameters are:

- A Hash for locating the container elements.
- The page section class.

Example:

```
class Container
  include PageObject
end

class MyPage
  include PageObject

  # Individual page section
  def container
    platform.page_for({tag_name: 'div'}, Container)
  end

  # Collection of page sections
  def containers
    platform.pages_for({tag_name: 'div'}, Container)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Justin,

This method was working for me until I had a `page_section` within a `page_section` and then it broke. Think you know what's going on? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59460873/4701396

Comment: @Bmoe, were you able to resolve your issue? It looks like you deleted the other question.